# Clearing the cakephp tmp/cache solves the issue for only one save call. What can be the reason?

Tags: database, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I modified the schema of mysql database(added a new table etc.), I cleared the tmp/cache(except directories).
Now the save in the new table happens only once(I have multiple save calls in a for loop and save happens for all of them) and fails from next time I enter the flow.

I am using cakephp 1.3.

What else should I check ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Got it.

The cache issue was one part of the problem, which got fixed by clearing the files in tmp/cache directory.

Learning is - 
If you make mysql schema changes(add new table / column etc.) in mysql, either clear the tmp/cache directory or set the debug level as 3 and refresh the page and set the debug level again to 0(if on production).

I was also getting a save error - mysql server has gone away, because in configs the wait_timeout value was 600 seconds. But my script was taking longer than that.
So model->save() was not working.

In my.cnf I updated the timeout to 4800 and restarted mysql and it fixed the problem.

Comment: Just a heads up to the interested, this method still works in cakephp 2.x

Comment: The highest level of debug is 2 actually.. :|, good thing the condition is > 0 when checking for debug.